# DSA verification calculation

Tags: python, math, cryptography, dsa

Am I missing something? from [FIPS180-2](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/archive/fips186-2/fips186-2.pdf), on page 25, it gives the values of u1, u2, g^u1 mod p, y^u2 mod p and v. i have calculated all the values except v. yet, when i do the math, my calculations refuse to be v = 0x8bac1ab66410435cb7181f95b16ab97c92b341c0. instead, i get v = 0xc5a54698ae8e5b94661134260594ff4e3f488e26, which is not equal to r, from before. im doing `(pow(g, u1, p) * pow(y, u2, p)) % q` to do the calculation, where `pow` is the builtin function, not the math module function

Comment: What values do you get for `pow(g, u1, p)` and `pow(y, u2, p)`?

Comment: i get the same values as the pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're skipping one mod `p` calculation. You should compute:

`(((pow(g, u1, p) * pow(y, u2, p))) % p ) % q`